# How to quickly calculate number of times a series crosses through a value?

Tags: r

I have a discrete cumulative random series in R:

```
x<-cumsum(rnorm(100))
```

When plotted:
[image]

What would be the best way to calculate how many times it crosses through a specific value; in this case, -2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(2)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
plot(x, type = "l")
abline(h = 0)
```

Find how many times x is greater than some value (0 in this case) using `rle` function on `x>0` vector.

```
length(rle(x > 0)$length) - 1
## [1] 6
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
#sample data
set.seed(17)
x<-cumsum(rnorm(100))
```

And we can calculate the crosses by subtracting the value we are intereted in and seeing how often the sign of the value changes from positive to negative

```
target <- 5
idx <- which(diff(sign(x-target))!=0)
print(paste("it crosses", length(idx), "times"))
```

and here's what the results look like with the crossing intervals highlighted

```
plot(x, type="l")
abline(h=target, col="green")
abline(v=c(idx,idx+1), col=c("red","blue"), lty=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help.

```
    x<-cumsum(rnorm(100))

    l1 = x >= 5
    n = length(x)

    temp = cbind.data.frame(l1[-1], l1[-n])
    colnames(temp) = c("l1", "l2")
    temp$val = (temp$l1 +temp$l2)
    sum(which(temp == 1))
```

The strategy here is to create logical and lagged logical, bind
and find the entries where two logicals differ (crosses the line).